# What is an "open Baire set"?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, definitions, borel-sets

In *Measures Which Agree on Balls* by Hoffmann-Jørgensen, it is stated that if $\varphi$ is a Baire function (which I presume means a pointwise limit of continuous functions), then $\{a<\varphi\}$ is an "open Baire set." What does this mean? Clearly they are not two separate adjectives, as $\{a<\varphi\}$ is clearly not always open.

Comment: Perhaps some background information would be helpful. An open set is not necessarily a Baire set (a set whose indicator function is a Baire function, or equivalently belongs to the Baire $\sigma$-algebra, generated by the zero sets). A compact Baire set is $G_\delta$, so in a compact Hausdorff space, the Baire open sets are the $F_\sigma$ open sets. Therefore if $X$ is uncountable, the complement of a point in the product space $2^X$ is a non-Baire open set. In a perfectly normal space, e.g. a metrizable space, every open set is a Baire set.

Comment: Of course, every open set in every topological space has *the Baire property* and belongs to the *Baire property $\sigma$-algebra*, which is why we have to be careful to distinguish these notions, all arising from generalizing results in Réné Baire's thesis.

Answer (score 6):

The function $\varphi$ in H.-J. is also assumed to be lower semi-continous, which is why $\{a<\varphi\}$ is open. This set is a Baire set because $\varphi$ is a Baire function.